# Opportunities to learn algebraic geometry outside of PhD education

Tags: soft-question, education

After a lot of deliberation, I decided to go to professional school instead of pursue academic mathematics. I don't have research aspirations, but I do have an obsession with "getting" esoteric mathematics. I performed quite well in some graduate complex and real analysis coursework as well as abstract algebra coursework (group and field theory) in undergrad. I was wondering what opportunities there are for me to do more coursework at a graduate level without actually enrolling in grad school. I think I burned my bridges for grad work when I asked my professors to write me recs for professional school. I doubt they'll take it seriously if I asked for more recs to do grad work. Plus, they probably don't remember me.

Also, I haven't done any theoretical math for a couple of years. Do you think it's too late?

Comment: Sometimes professors at local universities are OK with you auditing classes. I did this myself for a year. They even graded my exams.

Comment: Maybe start by reviewing some basics of algebra if you want to go further and haven't seen any of it for a while. I'd also want to learn topology if I were you. You need it for algebraic geometry.

Comment: Thanks both of you! Yes, I'm trying to do some reviewing on my own. I have done topology. No graduate level topology though.